# Is this ray tracing function that runs on the GPU, GPU safe?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, raytracing

I have tried to write a simple ray tracer in the fragment shader.
I have this function that is supposed to create a diffuse sphere as follows :

[image]

Here is the function :

```
vec3 GetRayColor(Ray ray)
{
Ray new_ray = ray;
vec3 FinalColor = vec3(1.0f);

bool IntersectionFound = false;
int hit_times = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < RAY_BOUNCE_LIMIT; i++)
{
    RayHitRecord ClosestSphere = IntersectSceneSpheres(new_ray, 0.001f, MAX_RAY_HIT_DISTANCE);

    if (ClosestSphere.Hit == true)
    {
        // Get the final ray direction

        vec3 R;
        R.x = nextFloat(RNG_SEED, -1.0f, 1.0f); 
        R.y = nextFloat(RNG_SEED, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        R.z = nextFloat(RNG_SEED, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        vec3 S = normalize(ClosestSphere.Normal) + normalize(R);
        S = normalize(S);

        new_ray.Origin = ClosestSphere.Point;
        new_ray.Direction = S;

        hit_times += 1;
        IntersectionFound = true;
    }

    else
    {
        FinalColor = GetGradientColorAtRay(new_ray);
        break;
    }
}

if (IntersectionFound)
{
    FinalColor /= 2.0f; // Lambertian diffuse only absorbs half the light
    FinalColor = FinalColor / float(hit_times);
}

return FinalColor;
}
```

For some reason, it seems like `hit_times` is constant.
This exact same code works on the CPU and produced the attached screenshot.

I'm not sure if this something to do with the GPU. But I've tested all the other functions and they work as expected.

1. The normals are fine and identical
2. The random number generator works fine and has been visualized

Here is the `Normal + RandomVec` or `S` visualized :

[image]

And it is the exact same when done on the **CPU**.

Here is the `hit_times` visualised on the **CPU**

[image]

But on the GPU, all three spheres are white.
Here is the full fragment shader : https://pastebin.com/3xeA6LtT
Here is the code that works on the CPU : https://pastebin.com/eyLnHYzr

Comment: To implement ray tracing you need [compute shader](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.1.-Ray-tracing-with-OpenGL-Compute-Shaders-%28Part-I%29)

Comment: I've seem multiple run on Fragment shaders

Comment: @VictorGubin https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tl3z4

Comment: Did you try to simplify your shader, see what changes?

Comment: @YakovGalka What do you suggest I try?

Comment: You're sure it's not a conversion issue? i.e. storing color from an unsigned int range [0..255] in a float that is expecting values in the range [0..1]? just try dividing by 255.0 to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All spheres are white most likely because `ClosestSphere.Hit` in `GetRayColor` function is always true.

I think the problem is in your `IntersectSceneSpheres` function.

In CPU code you return `HitAnything` which is defaulted to false. At the same time in the fragment shader you return struct `ClosestRecord` that remains uninitialized if nothing was hit.

Explicitly adding `ClosestRecord.Hit = HitAnything;` in the end of `IntersectSceneSpheres` function should fix it